# iOS: How to tell which album(s) a photo belongs to

Tags: ios, swift

How do I get the list of albums that a photo belongs to in iOS?

I'd appreciate an simple example or even just a link to documentation. I'm assuming this is simple, but my iOS skill level is very low and my google fu is failing me - I'm probably not using the right terms.

Scenario for context: The user has already synced a large collection of photos to their computer through the app. Now they're "archiving" (deleting) the oldest photos and videos to free up space. I want to allow them to preserve (not archive/delete) favorited photos and certain albums, no matter how old they are. I'm going to sort photos by date, filter out the favorited ones, filter out the ones that belong to excluded albums.